# Seam Weld injection in constructor : Unable to resolve any beans for Types

Tags: java, jboss-weld

I'm using Weld 1.0. Here's my situation: I have a class instantiating a Weld container which tries to instantiate a class `StartupShutdown`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WeldContainer weld;
    weld = new Weld().initialize();

    StartupShutdown startupShutdown = weld.instance().select(StartupShutdown.class).get();
}
```

Here's my class `StartupShutdown`:

```
public class StartupShutdown {

    @Inject
    public StartupShutdown(LoggingFileHandler loggingFileHandler) {
    }
}
```

I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308 Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [class fr.easycompany.easywrite.processes.StartupShutdown]; Bindings: [QualifierInstance{annotationClass=interface javax.enterprise.inject.Default, values={}, hashCode=2062316647}]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:728)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:102)
    at fr.easycompany.easywrite.EasyWrite.main(EasyWrite.java:18)
```

When I remove the parameter in the `StartupShutdown` constructor, it works.

Just for info, here's my `LoggingFileHandler`:

```
public class LoggingFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    @Inject
    public LoggingFileHandler(LoggingFormatter formatter) throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super("");
        this.setFormatter(formatter);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this parameter in my constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me! I just put `LoggingFileHandler` accidentally in my `src/test/java`. Works fine now. That's why the Bean could not be found.